# How do I expose a static class in a plugin without distributing the assembly and full MSIL for that class?

Tags: c#, plugins, interface, factory

I have a software in c# that exposes an interface for plugins. The plugins come with the ability to interact with a factory that creates certain tools for use in the plugin, however I do not want to distribute the code for the factory compiled along with the assembly for the plugin interface. The problem is that the factory is not an interface, its a static factory interior to the system. How do I expose what the factory does, without exposing what the factory is, so to speak.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the factory is a dependency of any plugins, you cannot obfuscate/encrypt it - plugins would not be able to use the factory if you did. You won't have to distribute the C# source to your factory, but you will have to include the compiled assembly with the factory, or the plugins will not work. So the short answer is "You can't".

Answer (score 0):

You could [use ILMerge](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge) to combine the assembly/assemblies for the factory with those for your software.  Other than that...  you are going to need to put the code for the factory somewhere, and if it is .NET that means distributing assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

One very unappealing option is to include the code to your static factory encrypted as a resource to another assembly, have the *another assembly* decrypt and compile it dynamically and then only ever use reflection to access it where necessary. Of course this is a possibility, though I would rarely recommend it.

A better option if you have to share your code is to *actually* share the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it inside a class that implements IFactoryThing, this way, client code would do a call on this interface instead.

Still you would have to distribute your code.

Comment: If the factory is **static** then how would an `interface` help here?

Comment: You do an Interface, in the real implementation, you just forward the calls to the static factory.